# Does violation of second law of thermodynamics become violation of law of conservation of Energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, entropy

Suppose if we were to violate the second law of thermodynamics and produce work entirely of heat from a single temperature. We can then heat a source of higher temperature with aforementioned work. We then use this  temperature difference to run a heat engine and repeat the process, apparently violating energy conservation. Can we generalise the second law in other cases similarly? Is it another way of saying energy conservation is not fulfilled?

Comment: *Suppose if we were to violate the second law of thermodynamics...* once you go there, anything physics says goes out the window because you've broken reality.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is a perpetual motion machine of the second kind, i.e. a machine which spontaneously converts thermal energy into mechanical work. This is different from a perpetual motion machine of the first kind, which produces work without the input of energy. It may indeed internally respect energy conservation while producing endless work, but more globally it would break energy conservation since it might for example endlessly charge up an energy store.

My guess is that once you break thermodynamics in one place it follows that energy conservation also breaks.

If you *demand* energy conservation, then there must be a limit to how much work the device can do, and then the violation of the second law will be finite. This [can actually happen for (carefully prepared) microscopic systems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.03323), but in macroscopic systems this will likely not be doable.

Comment: So you mean perpetual motion machine of second kind  locally ultimately leads to perpetual motion machine of first kind globally.

Comment: @KumarPranshu - I think so. But this might just be because the second kind breaks thermodynamics, a bit like how in math contradictions lead to arbitrary conclusions.

Comment: I would be very surprised if a violation of the second law inherently implied a violation of the first law. The second law tells me about how I am allowed to move energy around, not about how much of it there is. You would have to impose a restriction that all objects must have a finite heat capacity, so we have to get rid of our idea thermodynamic reservoirs, but an object with an infinite heat capacity at a finite temperature has an infinite energy, so it is not surprising that this leads to violations of energy conservation.

Comment: Even if the return cycle is irreversible, we still get the free energy.